# How to change the format of PHP-FPM error log?

Tags: php, stderr, fpm

probably a pretty simple question but how do I change the log format for FPM logs? An Entry looks like this for im in stderr:

```
2017/12/12 10:59:09 [error] 17#17: *6 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: 2017-12-12 11:59:09 > WARNING > WarningId: 1234 []
```

The thing I want to remove is the [error] part because in this example I'm logging a warning via monolog.

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 7.3 you can use

```
[www]
catch_workers_output = yes
decorate_workers_output = no
```

in php-fpm.conf (or php-fpm.d/ or pool.d/, depends on your system) to remove some extra decoration

Answer (score -4):

Php fpm doesn't seem to have a config for this error logging format. 
You could stop logging errors altogether by changing the logging level setting.

By a quick look into php-fpm sources it seems that it's the php error log format that is used for that.

And you do have control over that. One solution would be writing your own [error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)